# parsing compiler output from MS cl.exe

Tags: c++, qt-creator

In Windows with cl.exe ,

warning format is d:\path\Hello.cpp:131:2: <...>

error format is d:\path\Hello.cpp(694) : <...>

Somehow, qt-creator parses and shows these errors but does not open the file when clicked:
File not found.

I tried every toolchain creator 2.0 offers.

I'm using jam and had to manually redirect 2>&1 stdout to stderr console in order to see anything in the tab "build problems".

Answer (score 1):

I think you've answered your own question. Qt Creator reads the errors from stderr and stdout, and jam probably doesn't output them there (or in a way Qt Creator understands cl.exe)

Remember that Qt Creator does not work out of the box with jam, it never has. Perhaps that is the problem at hand. You doe get the error messages if you use a qmake or cmake project right?

Maybe posting [a bug report](http://bugreports.qt.nokia.com/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa) will help in getting jam support in Qt Creator.

Comment: No, jam is not the problem since I manually "redirect 2>&1". So, warnings are clickable. Errors do not work, since qt-creator thinks the bracketed line indicator Hello.cpp(694) was part of the filename.

Qt projects work fine, I probably need to write my own compiler-output parser.